# regex help skipping some text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture with regex `check color-attribute` and `red` and `blue` from the string below.

```
check color-attribute red green blue yellow pink
```

What I've tried but I also get other references to `red` and `blue`.

```
\bcheck\scolor-attribute\b|(red|blue)
```

But `red` and `blue` may not be in the same order every time and they may be mentioned later in the file. I'm guessing its a greedy thing but can't figure out how to resolve

Comment: What do you mean with other references? You use an alternation,  did you try a word boundaries around red and blue? `\bcheck\scolor-attribute\b|\b(red|blue)\b` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNl147/1) or without the capturing group `\b(?:check\scolor-attribute|\bred|blue)\b`

Comment: by other references I mean if red and/or blue are mentioned later in the file they also are seen as a match. Like in your demo link if you put red and blue as new lines they will match. https://regex101.com/r/uNl147/2

Comment: So you mean `check color-attribute` should always be there and red as well as blue should be there in the same string. Can they occur before `check color-attribute`?

Comment: So, do you want to martch `color attribute` that has either `red` or `blue` somewhere after it? See `\bcheck\scolor-attribute\b(?=[\s\S]*?\b(?:red|blue)\b)`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8V548/1). What is your *expected result* for that input string?

Comment: "check color-attribute" will always be there and the colors will always be after that on the same line. red and blue may not always be on the line. I want to know if they are. They may/probably will be mentioned later in the file. 
Example file<br />
check color-attribute red green blue purple pink
blah blah
blah blah
blah red
blah blue
blah blah

I only want to match the line  "check color-attribute"  IF red and/or blue are listed. And only if they're listed on that line.

Comment: Ugh.   Each of those "blah" should be a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around and I think this did what I wanted. Is it "right"
\b(?:check\scolor-attribute|\b(.red|.blue))\b

https://regex101.com/r/uNl147/4

Comment: That would also match [only red or blue](https://regex101.com/r/uNl147/5) when `check color-attribute` is not there and when there is a word character before it due to the alternation. Note that if you use the dot without escaping it matches any character except a newline. If red or blue should be there on the same line and you only want to match check color-attribute try `\bcheck\scolor-attribute\b(?=.*(?:red|blue))` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QU6s5q/1/)